# HybridAuth: How to bypass 'allow access' button

Tags: authentication-authorization, social-network

I have installed HybridAuth module to login in LinkedIn.  The following is the url through which user can log in from Popop window.

> http://www.mydrupal.com/hybridauth/window/LinkedIn?destination=node/38&destination_error=node/13

The logged in window gives 'allow access' button each time when open a popup.

**Question:**  How to bypass this 'allow access' button after the first attempt? I have already gone through various links but could not get proper idea.

**Screen shot** is as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am also face the same problem, But am using [ulgoin](https://www.drupal.org/project/ulogin) module. After login You must first authorize LinkedIn integration to use related features.

In this button available in user edit page. Once you have synchronized your details , in the above message not appear in the second attempt.

Thanks

[image]